# How do I use sp/pnp sp.search to find all Associated sites when querying a hub site Id

Tags: search, spfx, pnp-js

I'm making an app which lists all hub sites on an SP tenant. I want a user to click on a hub site and it shows all associated sites. Simple huh? No.
I cannot figure out how to use [sp.search](https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/sp/search/)

The documentation is notoriously assumptive. Here is what I've attempted:

```
export const GetAssociatedSites = async (hubId: string | undefined) => {
  const _sp = getSP();
  const finalArray: any[] = [];

  await _sp.search({
    StartRow: 0,
    QueryTemplate: "contentclass: STS_Site AND DepartmentId:1111*",
    Querytext: 'contentclass:STS_Site contentclass:STS_Web',
    //SiteTitle:{searchTerms} AND contentclass:STS_site AND DepartmentID:{{PageContext.hubSiteId}} 
    SelectProperties: [
      "Title",
      "SPSiteUrl",
      "WebTemplate",
      "SPWebUrl",
      "SiteName",
      "RelatedHubsites",
      "IsHubSite",
      "ParentLink",
      "Department",
      "Path"
    ],
    RefinementFilters: [`departmentid:string("${hubId}",linguistics=off)`],
    RowLimit: 500,
    TrimDuplicates: false,

  })
    .then((r: SearchResults) => {
      r.PrimarySearchResults.forEach((value) => {
        finalArray.push(value)
      });
      currentResults = r
    })
    console.log(currentResults, 'currentResults')
  return currentResults;
}
```

I get no results back. Any help with this?